# Windows Phone7 How to Play 3gp video?

Tags: windows-phone-7, grid, mediaelement, 3gp

I am using this code,

```
String video="http://bitcast-in.bitgravity.com/divum/espn/j2me/260811_Nojo-does-a-Maria.3gp";

 mediaplayer.Source = new Uri(video);
 mediaplayer.Play();
```

In layout:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaplayer"/>
```

video is not streaming.Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx
Try out this msdn link. u will get idea about media playback...
```

Answer (score 0):

3GP isn't supported on Windows Phone.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport

3GP is supported by Windows phone.